# Laravel whereIn not proper working with whereHas

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter

I make product listing and filtering page. so i need dynamic query in laravel. but while i am trying **whereIn** with **whereHas** so in select result some product are missing. my code is bellow. currently i have 3 main category her id is 1,2,3.

**Controller**

```
$input = $request->all();
        $products = Product::with('getMainCategory')->where('price', '>', $input['min'])->where('price', '<', $input['max']);

        $keys = [1, 2, 3];

        $products->whereHas('getMainCategory', function ($query) use ($keys) {
            $query->whereIn('main_category_id', $keys);
        });
        
        $products = $products->get();
```

**Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\ProductModel;

use App\Models\MainCategoryModel\MainCategory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Product extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];

    public function getMainCategory() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\MainCategoryModel\MainCategory', 'id', 'main_category_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Look like issue is with relationship keys


    public function getMainCategory() {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\MainCategoryModel\MainCategory', 'main_category_id', 'id');
    }

Answer (score 2):

Subquery should probably be

```
$query->whereIn('id', $keys);
```

But you can skip that all and just do

```
$input = $request->all();
$keys = [1, 2, 3];
Product::whereIn('main_category_id', $keys)->where(['price >' => $input['min'], 'price <' => $input['max']])->with(['getMainCategory'])->get();
```

Also, check foreign_key and local_key order in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) as @JohnLobo suggested.